# Calling a Windows C++ DLL from a UNIX FORTRAN console app

Tags: c++, unix, dll, fortran, wine

I'm looking for a way to call a Windows-built x86 DLL from a UNIX FORTRAN console app. I've read that Winelib might be able to help, but I've never used it before.

Can anyone please provide me with a good direction to start?

Comment: You may take a look at how `mplayer` uses Windows DLLs to decode videos in the unix environment.

Comment: If it's a C++ DLL (instead of a C DLL) then you may be SOL.  Different C++ compilers often use different name-mangling mechanisms, and output from one C++ compiler is almost always incompatible with libraries built using another C++ compiler -- even on the same platform.  (In fact, sometimes libraries built using a *different version of the same compiler* will be incompatible.)

Comment: So even if I used the Wine compiler it might not be able to successfully call a c++ DLL?

Comment: Unless you are using the same version of the same compiler, you are unlikely to get this to work.  C DLLs are a different animal entirely, because there is no name-mangling (due to a lack of function overloading).  C DLLs would probably be relatively easy to get working in this scenario.

Comment: The basic problem with Windows DLLs is that they do not use position-independent code and have to be relocated. I think it would be easier to just compile the Fortran code with Windows compiler and run the resulting PE executable under WINE. The emulation overhead is very low for console applications (as no expensive GUI calls have to be translated).